# How to integrate New Payment Gateway into [NopCommerce 3.10], If plugins not available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, payment-gateway, nopcommerce, payment-processing

Want to know what is the process for custom payment gateway integration with NopCommerce. If my payment gateway plugins not available ?

How to make a NopCommerce plugins for another payment gateway ? Which I required to integrate with my store .

What are the changes I need to be made, to integrate, new payment gateway ? into NopCommerce ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nopCommerce documentation](http://www.nopcommerce.com/documentation.aspx) have good guides on this. [Here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx) is how you create a plugin. And [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/76/how-to-code-my-own-payment-method.aspx) is how to write the payment method.

nopCommerce source code comes with a few payment plugins (i.e AuthorizeNET, PayPal, Google Checkout). Those are great real world examples to look at.

Good luck!